# Fixed point library prints less-accurate value than multiplying two floats

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision, fixed-point

I'm using this C++ fixed point library:

https://github.com/MikeLankamp/fpm

My program multiplies two values together and outputs them, first using fixed point, second using primitive floats:

```
#include <fpm/fixed.hpp>
#include <fpm/ios.hpp>    
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    fpm::fixed_16_16 x{2.2};
    fpm::fixed_16_16 y{ 2 };

    std::cout << (x * y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (2.2 * 2) << std::endl;
}
```

The fixed-point library outputs a less-accurate result than just multiplying two floats:

```
4.3999
4.4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2.2 is not exactly representable as a fraction with a power-of-two denominator. The fixed-point representation chosen here uses *fewer* bits than the single-precision floating point representation to represent 2.2, meaning the representational error is greater in the fixed-point format.

Comment: IEEE-754 `binary32` (here: `float`) value closest to 2.2 is 2.2000000476837158203125, while 16.16 fixed-point value closest to 2.2 to 2.1999969482421875.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for replying. What type should I use if my values need 9 decimal digits (exactly)?

Comment: If you need to perform floating-point computations with *exactly* nine decimal digits, chose a decimal floating-point library. I have not used it, or even looked at it, but Intel has a decimal floating-point library on [Netlib](https://netlib.org/misc/intel/), last updated in 2018.

Comment: @njuffa Must admit I'm not massively knowledgable in this area. I receive data, most of the time it's say 8 decimal places but there could be a 9 decimal place occasionally. I need to store these 8 and 9 decimal place numbers within a single container. This Intel library still meet my needs?

Comment: I haven't used Intel's library and I don't know your use case, so cannot tell whether this library would work for your use case or whether it would be overkill. *Maybe* all your use case needs is storing everything as integers in a suitable unit of measurement, say millivolts and millimeters?

Comment: Yeah that's literally it. The only math i'm doing is basic multiplication and division

Comment: @njuffa Apparently Boost cpp_dec_float too

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a decimal fixed-point type.